# C++ Class Member Constructor and Inheritance

Tags: c++11

In my code below, `className` and `classType` are throwing an "is not a nonstatic member or base class" error.

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    std::string className;
    int classType;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    // Default Constructor
    DerivedClass(){};

    // Member Constructor
    DerivedClass(
        std::string className_,
        int classType_
    ) :
    className( className_ ),
    classType( classType_ )
    {}

    // Destructor
    ~DerivedClass(){};
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite precise: You can not reference members of parent classes in your childs initialization list.

Rather pass them to your parents ctor in the initialization list:

```
DerivedClass(
    std::string className_,
    int classType_
) 
: BaseClass(className_, classType_)
```